# Identifying vertex to use with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertices

Wich is the best way to identify a vertex to use in a Geometry Node?

In my case I needed to know the number of a specific vertex to create a curve from this vertex, and it was tedious to find it.

There is a way to view the number of each vertex in the 'Evaluated Window' ?

Thanks for your time and help :)

[image: Vertex 201]

Comment: Try my addon here https://psyonic.gumroad.com/l/GN_Indices_Viewer

Comment: Thanks Psyonic I will tried it :)